# VPS CentOS 6.3 x64 recovery mode changes are not saved after reboot

Tags: centos6

i am running a CentOS 6.3 x64 OS on a VPS server, the server was having issues logging in to SSH using root credentials, it showed a message similar to "No Shell Exists, Access Denied" root login via console is also not working, however a normal wheel user can login.

So i had to boot the virtual machine into recovery for troubleshooting, however when i make any change and reboot the server the changes are not preserved.

I have already tried mounting the file system as read-write using following commands:

```
mount -a -o rw
mount -o remount, rw /
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

i am trying to add a new user and after mount the filesystem as read-write, i run the following commands

```
adduser username
passwd username
visudo
```

the changes are shown until i restart the system into normal mode, can anyone guide me how can i add a new root user from centos recovery mode or how to retain the changes made in recovery mode?

The VPS is hosted by FDC Servers using OnApp http://onapp.com
i believe they have their own recovery console as i am unable to find its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are booting into Rescue mode.  According to https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-boot.html, the default root partition is a temporary root partition.  The documentation says to run chroot /mnt/sysimage to fix this issue.

Comment: thanks i didn't notice, that my main partition was not mounting at all. used `mount /dev/xvda1 /mnt` to access it.